# Tokbox iOS: Video call disconnects when phone lock

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, tokbox

I am using tokbox for video calling in my iOS application. I am getting the issue when while video calling, when I lock the app, the stream gets disconnected and the call ends.

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/background-state.html) outlines running TokBox in the background, i.e. when the phone is locked.  The following is an excerpt from the limitations of running TokBox in the background:

> Apps cannot do the following while in the background state:
>
> - Use the camera as a video source for a publisher.

The documentation goes on to explain that you can keep an audio-only session active when running in the background, but not a video session.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for your reply, I totally agree that in background we cannot use camera as a video source. And when I put my app in background at the other end I get black screen and when I came back to foreground video starts rendering i.e. session do not disconnect in this case. But when I lock the screen, the session gets disconnected. Is there any solution for this?